# Dynamic or xml layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am little confused about the best way how should I design my application. I have used XML to define the position of objects.  But now when I'm developing application with more complex design I'm starting to think dynamic define of object can be more practical and suits all screen resolutions. Basically I would like to combine imageViews,  ImageSwitcher, TextSwitcher etc... Now I used XML code and it has more than 270 lines and also it is very chaotic, difficult to suit to all screen resolutions and every small change will crash my app. I would like to use percentage for set positions of objects, set scale of objects etc. Should I go on with XML or is it better if I start to use programmatically way to set positions of objects. I was looking for some books or tutorial about dynamic designing app but I always found only easy tutorials can be also done in XML. Has someone good hint for some book or tutorial about dynamic designing? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I used XML code and it has more than 270 lines

If you have that many lines in one xml file then I think you need to reconsider your design. Use `Fragments`, `ViewPager`, `ListView`, etc.. depending on your needs. But I don't know how you can have that many lines in one layout file.

> difficult to suit to all screen resolutions

I'm not sure how it is any easier doing the layouts programmatically. It really isn't that hard to support multiple screens. Use `dp`, `layout_weight` with `LinearLayout` when necessary, and other various tricks. [See this part of the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) about supporting different screens. For the most part, you just create different layout folders (3-6 maybe depending on what your need)

> Should I go on with XML or is it better if I start to use programmatically way to set positions of objects

It is typically easier to do your `layout`s through the xml. There are certain properties that **need** to be set in xml (can't think of any off-hand but they exist). I would only suggest doing it programattically when absolutely necessary. There have been times when I spent a bunch of time creating a layout programmatically then realized there was a much easier way to do it in xml.

The main reason, that I know of, to create a `layout`/`view` programmatically is if you don't know the number of/ what kind of `View`s will be used. Say, for example, if a user can press a `Button` to add another field to contacts. Even then you can do it in xml if you know the amount of `View`s available.

Make sure to go through the [Design Sections of the Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html) and you can Google design patterns, principles, etc... and find a lot of information.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I will try chech my XML code again and make it more easier and more structurable. From your answer is clear to me that I can create my design completely in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience - the **best way to create layouts is using XML**. This should not break your app every time. This sounds like you are not following best practices. One of the major drives behind using XML rather than programmatic view creation includes supporting different screen sizes and resolutions, and simplifying the use of Fragments.

That aside, there was a time about a year ago that I asked myself the same question. The result was an open source library for creating layouts using Java or XML (interchangeably), and supports customizing sizes based on the current display, using percentages, etc. It is called AbLE (Annotation-based Layout Engine), and is available for download here: https://github.com/phil-brown/AbLE .

I do not currently use this library (I use XML instead), and do not currently maintain it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for share your experience. It helped me a lot to understand how to design my app.